# how can i increase the speed of my C++ calculation

Tags: c++, mysql, function, math

i've wrote this code to calculate 3 formulas like: L`c=Lcb-Lca where Lcb and Lca equals to 7915,7*Log10(Tan(X1/2+45)) / G=Y2-Y1 / V=G/Lc` ->there is also some intermediate formulas which helps me to put the data in the right form. the problem is that i have a lot of data to treat and i want to find the way to optimize my code, if  it's possible.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "mysql/mysql.h"

using namespace std;


const string hostMySQL = "localhost";
const string userMySQL = "root";
const string database = "2_Generated_flights";
const string table = "8_airac_6_test";
const string passwordMySQL = "****";
const int port = 0;
const int clientflag = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    /* connection à MySQL */
    string request;
    MYSQL * connection = mysql_init(NULL);
    MYSQL_RES * result;
    MYSQL_ROW row = NULL;
            if(!mysql_real_connect(connection, hostMySQL.c_str(), userMySQL.c_str(),
               passwordMySQL.c_str(), database.c_str(),
               port, NULL, clientflag)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s\n",
        mysql_error(connection));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "connected to mysql" << endl;

   int sql_min_lat;
   sql_min_lat=mysql_query(connection, "SELECT ind, Lat_begin_segment, Lon_begin_segment, Lat_end_segment, Lon_end_segment from 8_airac_6_test");/*on choisit les variables nécessaires*/
   if (sql_min_lat !=0)
      {
     cout <<mysql_error(connection);
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    result=mysql_store_result(connection);
    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))){
        /*calcul ind*/
        int ind, degrees_lat_begin, degrees_lat_end, degrees_lon_begin, degrees_lon_end, G_int;
        float lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2,  minutes_lat_begin, minutes_lat_end, minutes_lon_begin, minutes_lon_end, G_diff, G_pr;
        double lat_beg_deg, lat_end_deg, lon_beg_deg, lon_end_deg, Lca, Lcb, Lc, G, TanV, V, Rv;
        ind=atoi(row[0]); 
        /*calcul lat_begin en degree*/
        lat1=atof(row[1]);      
        degrees_lat_begin = int (lat1);
        minutes_lat_begin = (lat1 - degrees_lat_begin) * 60;
        minutes_lat_begin=(int)minutes_lat_begin;
        if (minutes_lat_begin >-10 && minutes_lat_begin < 10) 
        {
           minutes_lat_begin= minutes_lat_begin/10;
           }
           else {
               minutes_lat_begin= minutes_lat_begin/100;
               }
        if (minutes_lat_begin ==1 || minutes_lat_begin==-1) {
            minutes_lat_begin=minutes_lat_begin/100;
        }

        lat_beg_deg=degrees_lat_begin + minutes_lat_begin;



        /*calcul lat_end en degree*/
        lat2=atof(row[3]);
        degrees_lat_end = int (lat2);
        minutes_lat_end = (lat2 - degrees_lat_end) * 60;
        minutes_lat_end=(int)minutes_lat_end;
        if (minutes_lat_end >-10 && minutes_lat_end < 10) 
        {
           minutes_lat_end= minutes_lat_end/10;
           }
           else 
               {
                   minutes_lat_end=minutes_lat_end/100;
                   }
        if (minutes_lat_end ==1 || minutes_lat_end==-1) {
            minutes_lat_end=minutes_lat_end/100;
        }
        lat_end_deg=degrees_lat_end + minutes_lat_end;

        cout << "Done degrees_lat_end!" << endl;

        /*calcul lon_begin en degree*/
        lon1=atof(row[2]);
        degrees_lon_begin = int (lon1);
        minutes_lon_begin = (lon1 - degrees_lon_begin) * 60;
        minutes_lon_begin=(int)minutes_lon_begin;
        if (minutes_lon_begin >-10 && minutes_lon_begin < 10) {
           minutes_lon_begin= minutes_lon_begin/10;
           }
           else 
            {
               minutes_lon_begin= minutes_lon_begin/100;
               }

        if (minutes_lon_begin ==1 || minutes_lon_begin==-1) {
            minutes_lon_begin=minutes_lon_begin/100;
        }
        lon_beg_deg=degrees_lon_begin + minutes_lon_begin;



            /*calcul lon_begin en degree*/
        lon2=atof(row[4]);      
        degrees_lon_end = int (lon2);
        minutes_lon_end = (lon2 - degrees_lon_end) * 60;
        minutes_lon_end=(int)minutes_lon_end;
        if (minutes_lon_end >-10 && minutes_lon_end < 10) {
           minutes_lon_end= minutes_lon_end/10;
           }
           else 
            {
               minutes_lon_end= minutes_lon_end/100;
               }

        if (minutes_lon_end ==1 || minutes_lon_end==-1) {
            minutes_lon_end=minutes_lon_end/100;
        }
        lon_end_deg=degrees_lon_end + minutes_lon_end;

        cout << "Done degrees_lon_end!" << endl;

         /*LCA*/        
        Lca=tan(45+lat_beg_deg/2);
        Lca=abs(Lca);
        Lca=7915.7*log10(Lca);
        Lca=abs(Lca);

        /*LCB*/      
        Lcb=tan(45+lat_end_deg/2);
        Lcb=abs(Lcb);
        Lcb=7915.7*log10(Lcb);
        Lcb=abs(Lcb);


        /*LC*/       
        Lc=Lcb-Lca;
        Lc=abs(Lc);

        /*G*/       
        G_diff=lon_end_deg-lon_beg_deg;
        G_diff=abs(G_diff);
        G_int=int(G_diff);      
        G_pr=G_diff-G_int;
        if (G_pr==1) {
            G_pr=0;
        }
        G_pr=G_pr*100;      
        G=G_int*60+int(G_pr);
        TanV=G/Lc;      
        V=atan(TanV)*57.2957795;

        if (lat_end_deg>lat_beg_deg && lon_end_deg>lon_beg_deg) {
            Rv=V;}
            else if (lat_end_deg>lat_beg_deg && lon_end_deg<lon_beg_deg) {
                Rv=360-V;}
                else if (lat_end_deg<lat_beg_deg && lon_end_deg<lon_beg_deg) {
                    Rv=180+V;}
                    else {
                        Rv=180-V;}

    char query[100000];
    sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO testRv(ind, Rv) VALUES(%i, %g)", ind, Rv);
    mysql_query(connection, query);
}

       mysql_close(connection);
       cout << "Done!" << endl;
  }
```

Comment: Step 1: Use a profiler to find out where the time goes.

Comment: Have you considered picking up a book and learning some good coding practices (like using RAII and not putting everything in `main`) before worrying about the speed of your application?

Comment: Well, you're obviously dealing with geographic coordinates, but it'd be much more helpful if you explain the gist of what you're doing rather than make me try to understand it all through your code.

Comment: A simple way might be to use -O3 optimization. If still too slow, see Step1 from NPE.

Answer (score 2):

To optimise code, you either try to change the algorithm after analysing the complexity of it and finding one with a lower complexity. There is no magic behind this task, you have to research to figure it out.

Or you profile the code using dedicated tools which are platform dependent. A profiler will tell you how much time is spent at every level of your program. Then it is possible to investigate where it is worth the effort to try and find a different approach.

There is no silver bullet to your question. You have to investigate and research.

Comment: I'd be tempted to tell the OP that code runs faster when it is nicely formatted.